# What does `file:///` mean and do?

Tags: files

What `file:///` "do"? How would an application use `file:///tmp/` differently from `file:///tmp/`? Does one force a certain mimetype?

---

Background: I'm trying to debug another, more complex application. For some reason, using this as an input

```
file:///tmp/test.html
```

works. But

```
/tmp/test.html
```

fails (for me only).

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you running? Which program is using the two syntaxes to address the file `test.html`? A standard program or script, or a program or script, that you have created yourself? What ownership and permissons are there on the file `test.html`?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme

Comment: note that as written this is an XY Problem like question.  The actual problem you have isnt really what you are asking about.  You should post a question giving details about the real problem, the application being used, and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. Just now the issue is an R script, that uses the Chrome API. But I'm finding it hard to unpick what's happening github.com/jhelvy/renderthis/issues/49, so asking a SO question is tricky. I suspect it's my system, but can't be sure

Comment: @csgillespie Without details on the script and how it calls things *other* than the Chrome API, I ahve to assume it's using Chrome/Chromium/Selenium-like interfaces (Selenium is Python that wraps around Chrome/Chromium or Firefox), and you're going to be restricted to URIs and not direct paths unless you have different coding/etc in place.  Chrome API sounds like URIs only, hence why `file://` works but not direct paths.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `file://` URI scheme is defined by [RFC 8089](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8089).  In essence, it defines a URL/URI that refers directly to a file for a web browser or web client to access, typically this is only used in modern days as a local file via URI.

The URI is not MIME-type aware nor does it force a specific MIME type.  It is up to the underlying application to determine MIME-type.

---

Note that `file:///tmp/test.html` working but `/tmp/test.html` not suggests that your application does not have the capacity to access the files directly without using a web browser like mechanism - this is something specific to the application and not related to the URI scheme definitions.

However, there could be sandboxing or other things in place on your system.  Which means you need to open a dedicated question for troubleshooting things.